# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'FirebaseInstallations' in Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I migrate my flutter app from flutter 2 to latest(3.3.8) successfully, now i am trying to run my flutter app on IOS simulator 11 pro max. Pod is installed successfully but it failed here.

[image: Build Ios App failed]

Here are the error messages with i try to run with command

```
flutter run --verbose
```

[image: error]

when i just simply run app with comand `flutter run`it throw following error

[image]

I tried all the available solutions suggested on stackoverflow and also issue reported in github but none work for me. I upgraded all packages to latest version. Also i added this line in my Pod file

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git =>'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git',:tag => '10.2.0'
```

Here are all my firebase packages i am using

```
firebase_messaging: ^14.1.1
cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
firebase_core: ^2.3.0
```

Comment: have you update all your packages for flutter 3.3, I had Also get this kind of error when i have update my flutter from 2.10 to 3.3 but Then i found to update the packages for flutter 3.3

Comment: yes i updated all packages to latest version